# Retrieve visitor count from redis 'incrby' and create Popular Post

Tags: laravel, redis, predis

I have a news website and i want to create popular post based on user visit with interval between 7 Days.

I created counting mechanism using Redis::incrby() with prefix :

```php
Redis::incrby( 'news:popular:count:' . $news_id . ':' . \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'), 1 );
```

but the problem is, i don't know how to retrieve it using `GET` and sort the value.

So i expect to get the popular post based on user count.

Is there any way to achieve it and get the popular post? or is there any better method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own solution and i will publish it here so if another user facing similar issue like me, you can use this solution.

First, we retrieve the key using `Redis::keys` using wildcard to get a list of a keys that contain the post count :

```php
$popular     =   Redis::keys('news:popular:count:*');
```

and then we create empty array to store the count data :

```php
$get_count   = [];
```

after that we use foreach to explode and get the news_id and then get the post count

```php
foreach ($popular as $key => $res) {
            // Get news_id
            $news_id    =   explode( ":", $res );

            // Get count each post
            $get_count[ $news_id[3] ]  =   Redis::get( $res );
}
```

and then we sort the array result from high to low using `arsort()` method

```php
// Sort news count from high to low
arsort( $get_count );
```

That's it, the hardest part that i'm facing already solved. Maybe you can share a better answer if you have.